# My ResultSet is fetching only 7500 rows, but I want to fetch all my rows which are available in database table

Tags: java, jdbc

My `ResultSet` is fetching only 7500 rows, but I want to fetch all my rows which are available in the database table.

For this I used `resultset.setFetchSise(100000)`, even though it is fetching only 7500 rows.

I would happy if any body help me in this regard.

Comment: Would mind post a bit of the code you written there, does it contain a  LIMIT clause in your query which possibly could be limiting your resultset

Comment: I written the code as:String selectFromAssetTabelQuery = "SELECT SERIALNO FROM ASSET";    
rs1 = destinationStmt.executeQuery(selectFromAssetTabelQuery);
rs1.setFetchSize(100000);
Vector<String> serialNoVec=new Vector<String>();
while(rs1.next()){
  serialNoVec.add(rs1.getString("SERIALNO"));
}

Comment: then probably your DB is really having only 7500 rows.  BTW, fetch size is about how much it fetch for one round trip, but it is not restricting how many TOTAL record it is fetching.

Comment: `setFetchSize` has nothing to do with the maximum number of rows retrieved from the server; it hints to the driver (as a performance optimization) how many rows it should attempt to fetch in a single database call. Also add updates to your own question to the question itself, don't use comments.

Comment: agree with @MarkRotteveel, also it would be good if you run `SELECT COUNT(SERIALNO) FROM ASSET` to make sure you really have that number of rows

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) states -

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement. If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored. The default value is zero.

So this is only giving a hint that you want more returned.

As already stated you would need to post more information to advise on your problem -

- Sample code - are you returning CLOBs, ...
- Driver used

Comment: Thank you for advise: 
DriverName: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver
DriverVersion: 1.1.1501.101
DriverMajorVersion: 1
DriverMinorVersion: 1

Comment: Code:::::::::::String selectFromAssetTabelQuery = "SELECT SERIALNO FROM ASSET"; 
rs1 = destinationStmt.executeQuery(selectFromAssetTabelQuery);
rs1.setFetchSize(100000);Vector<String> serialNoVec=new Vector<String>();
int index=0;
while(rs1.next()){
 serialNoVec.add(rs1.getString("SERIALNO"));  
    
}

Comment: actuallly, In My database table I have 8000 records

Comment: I am not returning any CLOBs at all. Thanks.

Comment: Try void [setMaxRows(int max)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: @farrellmr Setting `maxRows` makes no sense, by default it should be unlimited.

Comment: @Murali Why are you using such an old driver? It might be a bug that has already been fixed in a more recent SQL Server driver.

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments